# OS X 10.10 - apache will not run PHP from homebrew

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

I have installed php55 with homebrew to get postgresql support and linked the php module in apache.

```
LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Still my phpinfo() - shows PHP 5.5.20 (the built in  OS X). But from terminal I get PHP 5.5.26.

What can I do to fix this and force apache to use PHP 5.5.26?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I solved this with removing PHP55 (brew uninstall php55 and related php pdo_psql) and reinstalling (brew install php55 --with-postgresql) since I needed postgresql support. I then made sure apache was stopped and started it again. I needed to edit the php.ini file that is now at

/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini

Everything seems fine now and using the new PHP55 I installed with homebrew.